# grabbing the values of tags on a button when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a button written in html.slim

```
input.delete-item-btn#item type='image' src=the_icon()  name=item['store']
```

This code repeats for every item on the page (via a ruby loop). In html that is ~

```
<input class="delete-item-btn" id="item" type="image" src=the_icon()  name=item['store'] />
```

In javascript, I want to print the item['store'], which is the name of the button, when the button is pressed.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('.delete-item-btn').mousedown(function(ev) {
  user_id = document.getElementById('item').name
  alert(user_id)
});
```

but this just always prints the store of the first item on the page since all buttons have the same id: 'item'

In short:
Is there some way to print the name tag of the button pressed when that button has no distinguishing characteristics other than it was the button that is pressed and it has the store that I want?

Comment: Just do `alert(this.name)` and it should work

Comment: And you shouldn't have duplicated ID's

Comment: Thanks, I agree, i'll get rid of them,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the clicked element with `this`, no need to look it up again

```
$('.delete-item-btn').mousedown(function(ev) {
  var user_id = this.name;
  alert(user_id)
});
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, ill accept it when SO allows me to.